# Como puedo hacer un delete a partir de un query en mongoDB?

Tags: base-de-datos, mongodb

mi duda es, como puedo generar un delete para que a partir de un query se eliminen 2 campos en un objeto dentro de una coleccion en MongoDB

Este es el query, y el responde del mismo es el sig
[image]

Este es el resultado, como se puede ver dentro de la imagen, en el atributo de Inventory hay un objeto, lo que quisiera hacer es que, Sí dentro del array los objetos asociados a Inventory, el StoreId tiene un numero como valor entonces hay que eliminar los campos satus e inventorystatus

[image]

la duda es cual seria la sentencia para eliminar los campos dentro de inventory cuando storeid tenga un numero?

Comment: en tu caso, quieres que el elemento 0 del array solo quede entonces con las propiedades `storeId` y `stock`? y el elemento 1 no sea modificado? y quieres hacer este proceso para muchos documentos al tiempo?

Comment: Exacto, pero esto solo y cuando el storeId tenga asignado un valor numerico ya que tambien puede tener asignado el valor 'Online' y en ese caso no se debe hacerle nada a ese array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entonces lo que puedes hacer es un `update` junto con `$unset`; y usando los `arrayFilters` especificas que elementos deseas cambiar, así:

```
db.collection.update({
  "inventory.storeId": { //Condiciona los documentos que vas a seleccionar de la colección
    $regex: "[\\d]+$" //sólo los que el inventory.storeId sea un número
  }
},
{ //Especificas que vas a hacer
  $unset: {   //$unset porque lo que quieres es quitar propiedades
    "inventory.$[x].status": "", //Quieres quitar el status de los elementos x
    "inventory.$[x].inventoryStatus": "" //y quieres quitar el inventory Status de los elementos x
  }
},
{
  arrayFilters: [ //Especificas las condiciones que debe tener el elemento x para que sea tomado en cuenta
    {
      "x.storeId": {
        $regex: "[\\d]+$"  //que el storeId sea un número
      }
    }
  ],
  multi: true,  //Para que haga el cambios sobre múltiples documentos, no solo sobre el primero encontrado
})
```

Para eso se usa el operador `$[] (operador posicional filtrado)`: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/

Donde especificamos un identificador y luego mediante el `arrayFilters` decimos las condiciones que debe tener ese identificador para que sea cambiado.

Te dejo un ejemplo en mongo playground: https://mongoplayground.net/p/nXfNECCARok